# Identical Distribution and Pointwise limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n,Y_n$ have identical distribution for each $n$. Suppose $X_n\to c$ a.s. Is it true that $Y_n\to c$ as well? I can only show that $Y_n\to c$ in distribution base on what I have.

Comment: What if you make $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of independent random variables, but the random sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a.s. convergence, then the answer is NO.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathsf{P}) = ([0, 1), \mathcal{B}([0,1)), \operatorname{Leb})$ where $\operatorname{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0, 1)$. Then for each $m \geq 0$ and $0 \leq k < 2^n$, consider

$$ Z_{m,k} = \mathbf{1}_{ \left[\frac{k}{2^m},\frac{k+1}{2^m} \right) }. $$

Now enumerate the set $\{ (m, k) : m \geq 0 \text{ and } 0 \leq k < 2^m\}$ as a sequence $\{ (m_i, k_i) \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ so that this increases in lexicographical order. Then define

$$ X_i = Z_{m_i, 0} \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y_i = Z_{m_i, k_i}. $$

Notice that $X_i \stackrel{d}{=} Y_i$ for all $i$ and $X_i \to \mathbb{1}_{\{0\}}$ pointwise everywhere, hence $X_i \to 0$ almost surely. But it is easy to check that $Y_i$ fails to converge pointwise everywhere.